# Why does sub-netting not give us more addresses?

Tags: ipv4, subnet

Sorry if this is dumb, but I am very knew to learning about networks.

Here is my reasoning?

Let's take the address, 24.50.12.4

if we subnet it with /16 then the network address is 24.50 + host is 0.0.12.4
if we subnet it with /24 then the network address is 24.50.12

It feels like this means we have increased the number of available networks?

What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: You can get more networks, but not addresses. See [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for how it all works.

Comment: /16 has two IPs for network and broadcast address to segment subnet. EACH /24 has two IPs for network and broadcast